# Ipopt installation

Tags: failed-installation, ipopt

I tried to install the Ipopt package on my Mac (macOS Catalina, 10.15.0) following this installation guide:
https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html

I installed ASL as the linear solver and made it to the point 3. `make`without any further issues. However, when I run `make test`, I receive the following error message:

```
cd test; /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make test
  CXX      hs071_main.o
  CXX      hs071_nlp.o
  CXXLD    hs071_cpp
  CC       hs071_c.o
  CCLD     hs071_c
ln -s ../examples/hs071_f/hs071_f.f hs071_f.f
  F77      hs071_f.o
  F77LD    hs071_f
ld: library not found for -lmkl_core
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [hs071_f] Error 1
make: *** [unitTest] Error 2
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? It seems like it can't find the mkl library...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to install the Intel MKL library https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/onemkl.html since it is not part of Mac OS.